# If $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f(x^n)\,dx=f(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, riemann-integration

> $\textbf{The Problem:}$ Prove that if $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, then
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f(x^n)\,dx=f(0).$$
>   Note: Here we are using the Riemann integral.

$\textbf{My Thoughts and Attempt:}$ Choose $0<\delta<1$. Since $f$ is continuous on a compact interval, it follows that it is also uniformly continuous, on $[0,1]$ and hence, on $[0,\delta]$. Thus,  $f(x^n)\to f(0)$ uniformly on $[0,\delta]$. Therefore,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\delta f(x^n)\,dx=f(0)\cdot\delta.$$
Since $0<\delta<1$ was arbitrary, it follows that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f(x^n)\,dx=f(0).$$

---

$\textbf{My Concerns:}$ I am not entirely convinced that I have executed my $\delta$ trick, which turns the problem into a double limit, correctly. Could anyone please provide some feedback on my proof above and whether the introduction of $\delta$ is handled appropriately?

Thank you for your time and appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Why do you assume uniform continuity when the problem statement doesn't?

Comment: a continuous function on a compact interval is uniformly continuous

Comment: @MariosGretsas I think J.G's point is you should say that. You should mention the theorems you use

Comment: @qbert Noted. Thank you for the suggestion. I will add the theorems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lines after "as $0<\delta<1$ was arbitrary is fuzzy. You do not need a double limit to conclude.

The idea is a good one though. I would split the integral into two pieces, one on which you can argue by uniform continuity, and one on which you can make $\delta$ small enough so that it does not matter. This I believe is what you are missing.

Fix $1>\delta>0$. Examine 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1f(x^n)\mathrm dx=
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^{1-\delta}f(x^n)\mathrm dx+
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{1-\delta}^1 f(x^n)\mathrm dx
$$
Provided both exist. On the first, argue as you did. On the second, bound the integral uniformly in $n$ using the maximum $M=\max_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)|$.
Then,
$$
\sup_n \left| \int_{1-\delta}^1f(x^n)\right|\leq M\delta
$$

Now you can say since your choice of $\delta$ was arbitrary, the limit is what it should be.